# APA6-package in man-mode - getting rid of "running head" on first page

Tags: apa6, german

I am using the `apa6` document class with the `man` option to write my bachelor-thesis.

On the first Page, top left corner, the actual running head ("FAAFAAFAAFAA") is preceded by `Running Head:`. My supervisor wants me to remove this, as he does not consider it to apa-standard. How could I achieve this?

Note: I do not intend to start a discussion about whether this might be right or wrong due to the apa manual. I care about producing a thesis meeting my supervisor's demands, even if it means violating apa standards.

Below is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,man]{apa6}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{FAAFAAFAAFAAFAA}
\shorttitle{FOOFOOFOOFOOFOOFOOFOOFOO}
\begin{document}
LELELELELELEE
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice MWE, by the way!

Comment: Off-topic: Please don't use either the `ngerman` or the `german` package -- they're both obsolete. Instead, do use either `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` or `\usepackage[german]{babel}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of going about achieving your adviser's formatting requirement is to insert the following instruction immediately after `\begin{document}`:

```
\thispagestyle{otherpage}
```

(Inserting this instruction before `\begin{document}` works as well, but I think that it's less clear as to which page is affected.)

Why does this work? Let's examine the definitions of the `titlepage` and `otherpage` page styles that are provided by the `apa6` document class:

```
\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{%
    \lhead{\rheadname: \MakeUppercase{\@shorttitle}}%
    \rhead{\thepage}%
}
\fancypagestyle{otherpage}{%
    \lhead{\MakeUppercase{\@shorttitle}}%
    \rhead{\thepage}%
}
```

Elsewhere in the document class file, we have `\def\rheadname{Running head}`. Note that it doesn't suffice to undefine `\rheadname`, as there'd still be a colon, `:`, and an empty space ahead of the actual running head. Redefining the `titlepage` page style (and make it act like the `otherpage` page style) is possible in principle, but then one also needs to run `\thispagestyle{titlepage}` one more time for the change to take hold. That's why I'm suggesting switching the page style for the title page to `otherpage`.

Comment: your suggestion solved the proplem perfectly, thank you very much! 
I tried looking into the document class itself, as you did, but lacking foreknowledge and time, I was not able to make any sense of the provided code.
Also, thank you for the little illustration why alternative solutions wouldn't have worked, i will try and work myself into this topic when I can focus a little more on the specialties of LaTeX.